# QGIS 2.14 c++ standalone application crashes using QgsMapToolIdentify

Tags: qgis, features, c++, identify

```
lResultList.append(mpIdentifyTool->identify(lCoord.x(),lCoord.y(),QgsMapToolIdentify::TopDownStopAtFirst, QgsMapToolIdentify::VectorLayer));
```

leads to crash of app. It happens when layers provided by "memory" provider exist on canvas. With layers provided with "ogr" code works normally. Is there way to fix this? Or is there another way to select feature by clicking on it with mouse?